# Validity test error when defining fields in a Reference Class

Tags: r, validation, reference-class

### Context

I've defined two RCs. The first is `VectorCharacterElements`. I've assigned a validity test to it.

```
VectorCharacterElements <- setRefClass(
  "VectorCharacterElements",
  fields = list(vec = "character", el1 = "character", el2 = "character")
)

ValidVectorCharacterElements <- function(object) {
  if (length(object$vec) < 2) {
    cat("Length of `vec` must be greater than or equal to two.")
    cat("\n")
    return(F)
  } 
  return(T)
}

setValidity("VectorCharacterElements", ValidVectorCharacterElements)
```

I'm trying to define a second RC, `VectorCharacterElementsDistance`. It uses `VectorCharacterElements` as a field.

```
VectorCharacterElementsDistance <- setRefClass(
  "VectorCharacterElementsDistance",
  fields = list(vce = "VectorCharacterElements", d = "numeric")
)
```

However, I'm getting an error when I run the above code.

> Length of `vec` must be greater than or equal to two. Error in
>   validObject(.Object) :    invalid class “VectorCharacterElements”
>   object: FALSE

The error is from the validation method I defined for `VectorCharacterElements`.

### Question

How can I keep validation for `VectorCharacterElements`, and ensure `vce` is of type `VectorCharacterElements` in `VectorCharacterElementsDistance`?

### Observations

The error won't present itself if I use `contains`.

```
VectorCharacterElementsDistance <- setRefClass(
  "VectorCharacterElementsDistance",
  contains = "VectorCharacterElements",
  fields = list(d = "numeric")
)
```

But, I would like to avoid inheriting from `VectorCharacterElements`.